# Twitter API direct_messages Inbox

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

`"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/direct_messages/events/list.json"` and the soon to be replaced `"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/direct_messages.json"` give a history of your direct messages by date... however, what if I have two threads... one that's a year old and on that has more than 20 more recent messages inside it? I'll technically only get one thread and I'll have to fetch the entire list of messages to make sure I have all the threads.

What I really want is a call to get the list of threads, and then fetch the messages based on that thread... is this not possible with the Twitter API? I can't find that endpoint anywhere

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem?

Comment: I have not sadly...